# T-Sql business rule calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a complicated problem that needs to be solved in t-sql. Possibly without a cursor or a loop.

Given the following table with customer’s payment setup.

```
ID  Frequency   Amount  Start Date  End Date
1   Monthly     100     01-01-2016  N/A(ongoing)
```

The customer wants to know how much he\she will have to pay for the month of November. 
If they were to close the account on 15 nov 2016.

**For example:**

Assume the customer wants to close their account on 15-nov-2016 and wants to know the $amount they will be paying from 1st of November to 15 of November.

**Calculation**

The frequency cycle for the customer payment is Monthly.
Taking the frequency into account we know that:

- Customer start date of November will be 1st of November
- The end date will be 30 November

**Calculation formula**

```
(DayUpToCloseDate/DaysInNov) * Amount = amount customer is asking.

DaysUpToCloseDate = 15 (diff 1st of nov and 15th of nov)
DaysInNov = 30
Amount = 100
(15/30)*100 = 50
```

So we can tell the customer he/she will be paying 50$ in November if they were to close the account on 15th of November.

Comment: Where are you getting the close date? Seems like if you have the table format listed and use a parameter to pass in the date you could easily use DATEDIFF() and EOMONTH() for your calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to declare the 2 variables, the date in question and the monthly amount due.

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2017-11-15'
DECLARE @amountDue int = 100
```

Then to get the month to date amount due we can use:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@date) AS FLOAT)/DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0)-1) * @amountDue AS [MonthToDateAmountDue]
```

Here is how we got there.

```
SELECT
    --This gets the first day of the next month and subtracts 1 day, getting the last day of the month the date falls in.
    DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0)-1 AS [LastDayOfMonth]
    --We now extract the day date part of the last day of the month to get the total days in the month.
    ,DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0)-1) AS [DaysInMonth]
    --Finally, we get the day date part from our @date and divide by the total days of the month to get the percentage of the month we have completed.
    --Since int does not do decimals, we use a float.
    ,CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@date) AS FLOAT)/DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0)-1) AS [PercentageOfMonthCompleted]
    --And mulitply it by the amount due.
    ,CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@date) AS FLOAT)/DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0)-1) * @amountDue AS [MonthToDateAmountDue]
```

Edit: So, I just learned about the EOMONTH function. This can be shortened to

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@date) AS FLOAT)/DATEPART(DAY,EOMONTH(@date)) * @amountDue AS AS [MonthToDateAmountDue]
```

Comment: Why do you need a second variable if the return value of the select statement is the desired number?

Comment: @amountDue is the amount due per month. The value returned is the amount due if paid at the select date. So if someone closes their account part way through the month, they are not being billed for the full month.

But I see the confusion. Edited to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, one more question. Can you please try include fortnightly frequency into the calculation as well? I.E there is a possibility that payment might be setup for fortnightly instead of monthly.

Comment: This can be done as is for any datepart listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql. Unfortunately, fortnight is not an option. However if you can determine the start date to determine which weeks are the first week and which weeks are the second, something similar could be done for fortnight.